# Can we train a model with torch on machines with GPU and use this model on a machine with CPU only?

Tags: deep-learning, torch

I am using the torch backend with cuda to train a model on machines with GPU. After the model being built, can I use this mode to do inference on machine with CPU only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, before saving your model, remember to run `model:double()` convert your model weight from Cuda tensor to Double tensor

```
require 'cutorch';
require 'cunn';
require 'nn';
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Linear(10, 20))


print(model:parameters())
model:cuda();
print(model:parameters())
model:double();
print(model:parameters())
```